# Разрешить http iframe на https страницах

Tags: http, https, iframe

Есть сайт на https, когда iframe подгружает другой сайт с поддержкой https, то отображает нормально, а если http, то браузер пишет смешанный контент. Нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было загружать любые сайты и с http и https на сайте с https. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Никак, это снижает безопасность и браузеры этого не допустят

Comment: Тогда какие варианты есть замены? Сам сайт рекламная площадка и за просмотр сайтов платятся деньги, сайты показываются в iframe. Возможно можно заменить iframe чем-то другим?